# Can php pull in a variable set in an XML call using a dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, xml

Hi I am new to this forum and hoping someone could help I have set a dropdown menu with option value dynamically pulling in from a mysql database. these values when selected use xml to return the ids and content according to whats been selected. In the url there is a variable which im having trouble getting PHP to create a session variable from it. Can this be done? Thanks

Thanks, this is the code where the url is set

`function showUser(str)
     {
     var xmlhttp;
     if (str.length==0)
     {
     document.getElementById("state").innerHTML="";
     return;
     }
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else{
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send(null);
     }`

The php call '$id = $_GET['q'];
$_SESSION['q'] = $id;'

Comment: You have a dropdown menu with values retrieved from database. When selected, what XML is used? Which URL variable is problem, how the URL looks like? What session variable you need to create. Please explain more and provide the code.

Comment: Hi I have provided the code above. I am also using buttons on the same page as the drop down which when clicked displays some content according to the selection in the drop down menu.The buttons use ajax calls to pull in php pages but need it to link with the drop down.

Comment: Ok, and where do you get the error? This code looks like after `showUser()` function is called the element with id `state` will have innerHTML updated with data recieved from PHP. Session variable should be also set, but this will take effect (in PHP) after page is reload.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
http://www.domain.com/?action=delete

$action = $_GET['action'];
$_SESSION['action'] = $action;
```

Comment: No its not been solved I have attached the code to the question.

Comment: PLease unlock this post by click on de v sign I will check it later for you.

Comment: Is this what you want or mean? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Hi I managed to use the example given above and worked. Thanks for your help. I just copied the $_SESSION['q'] with session_start(); at top to my other pages :)

Comment: Great, can you close this topic.